# Python tarfile compress an object in memory

Tags: python

I am trying to use tarfile to add a file in memory and then writing it back to disk, but the issue i am having is that in my final output, when i extract the newly created tar.gz file, i am getting an empty file. What am I doing wrong in my code?

```py
import tarfile
import io

with open('logo.png', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

fh = io.BytesIO()
with tarfile.open(fileobj=fh, mode='w:gz') as tar:
    info = tarfile.TarInfo('some.png')
    tar.addfile(info, data)

with open('/tmp/test/test.tar.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(fh.getvalue())
```

I also tried doing `tar.addfile(info, fh.write(data))`, but that just creates a corrupted tar file.

Comment: I believe you need to set `info.size` to the size of your data.  It defaults to zero, and according to the docs it controls the number of bytes written into the archive.

Comment: @jasonharper yep, tried that by setting `info.size = len(data)`, and its sets it correctly according to my traceback, but getting a `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'` error when i add the size..

Comment: I think thats because as the docs explain `If fileobj is given, it should be a binary file, and tarinfo.size bytes are read from it and added to the archive`. So the size doesnt really have to be set.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`TarFile.addfile()` takes a file-like object.

When the documentation says:

> tarinfo.size bytes are read from it and added to the archive.

It means that `tarinfo.size` is used to determine how many bytes to read. Therefore, you need set `tarinfo.size` appropriately.

The only thing you need to do is read the data from the source, count the length, then load that data into a BytesIO object:

E.g.

```
import tarfile
import io

with open('logo.png', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    source_f = io.BytesIO(initial_bytes=data)

fh = io.BytesIO()
with tarfile.open(fileobj=fh, mode='w:gz') as tar:
    info = tarfile.TarInfo('logo.png')
    info.size = len(data)
    tar.addfile(info, source_f)

with open('test.tar.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(fh.getvalue())
```

or a more memory efficient way, seek the source file:

```
f = open('logo.png', 'rb')
f.seek(0,2) # go to the end
source_len = f.tell()
f.seek(0)

fh = io.BytesIO()
with tarfile.open(fileobj=fh, mode='w:gz') as tar:
    info = tarfile.TarInfo('logo.png')
    info.size = source_len
    tar.addfile(info, f)

with open('test.tar.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(fh.getvalue())

f.close()
```